# flutter android firebase notification not caught when running in background

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have implemented firebase notification in a flutter app running on android. Below is the function that we have defined for handling background messages

```
     FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler); 
@pragma('vm:entry-point') 
            Future<void>     _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {   
            await Firebase.initializeApp();   
    // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,   
            // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.   
        print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}'); }
```

below is the notification body that is being sent

```
{
 "to" : "eYQ8cukfTzW:APA91b,
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Notification Body",
     "title": "Notification Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }
}
```

We are using firebase_messaging: ^14.1.0

My call handler is above my main function

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point') //this is used for where indicates this function not removed while releasing
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
 await Firebase.initializeApp();
 print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}
```

Inside my main.dar
I am calling this like this

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler); //for handling background
```

And for foreground messages like this

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions( alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
```

it works perfectly fine while the app is in the foreground. However, if the app is closed then the notification is not going to the background message handler

The notifications appear when the app is running. However, if the app is closed, the app does not catch any notifications. it seems like the background method does not get invoked when notifications are received. Can anyone please help how to fix this?

Comment: Why did you used await Firebase.initializeApp(); inside _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler function ?

Comment: Could you show the complete code snipper where Firebase is getting initialized? And how you are setting up the handler?

Comment: I have edited my post so please check the firebase initialization and the background message handler